# I am trying to connect oracle 12c to django 2. for that i unlocked HR schema but when i run python manage.py migrate it gives me error

Tags: python, django, oracle, oracle12c

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
            'NAME': 'orcl',
            'USER': 'hr',
            'PASSWORD':'hr@pdborcl',
```

}
}

error:

```
 django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

but I am able to login to DB using this username and password.

Comment: Are you sure the password isn't just pdborcl? Sorry if that's a stupid question, just looks unusual. The fact that you're getting the error means that you've connected to the database, so that's good.

Comment: Yup password is correct because I am able to connect when I login through command prompt to sqlplus